# return in Node.js function not work

Tags: javascript, node.js

I create a function in Node.js I want to return value from it and want to get value when I call this function.

This is my function

```
module.exports = {
  pdfDownload :function()
  {
    return true;

  }
}
```

Now This is another file where I call this function

```
var objpdfApi = require('./pdfapi.js');
 var abc = objpdfApi.pdfDownload()
 console.log(abc)
```

but It give result "undefined"

I am following this Javascript concept

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_state_return_pi
```

Now what should I do for returning value??

Comment: Nothing wrong here, you would need to show all of your code. Alternatively try with `exports.pdfDownload = function() { return true; }` but I'm convinced you're overriding the function else where or order is messed up.

Comment: You're not using this in a browser, right ?

Comment: @TGrif  yes right

Comment: Your module file name is _pdfapi.js_, placed in same directory, right ?

Comment: @TGrif yes function call successfully but not return value